# Where is the ocr translated text saved in the google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

Im following this tutorial to set up the google vision ocr: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr. In the tutorial it says that translated text from images is saved in your google cloud storage. Ive created a bucket to save the translations but when I try to upload an image in the command prompt with this command: gsutil cp PATH_TO_IMAGE gs://YOUR_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME. It succesfully adds the image to my image bucket, but I don`t know where it puts the text translation.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#functions_ocr_translate-python), it saves your translations back to Cloud Storage. Try checking the output .txt file in your GCS bucket via these [options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects).